# What does syntax like "v.*" mean in MySQL Query?

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following PHP code, with MySQL code that I'm having trouble understanding:

```
$result = $conn->query("SELECT v.*, (select count(*) from $table2 where ParentSyncGuid=v.SyncGuid) children FROM $table2 v WHERE v.ParentSyncGuid IS NULL OR v.ParentSyncGuid = ''");
```

The $table2 is defined earlier as the correct MySQL table.

However, "v" is not the name of any variable, table, or anything I can understand -- can someone explain the above query? The table being queried has entries where there are a few "root" entries, and every other entry has a parent that eventually links back to the root entries, hence the parent/id syntax, and the above code is meant to find just the root elements from my understanding... but I cannot get it to work and have never seen the "v." syntax before, and cannot find any documentation on it.

Comment: `v` is an alias  for `$table2`

Comment: `v` is an alias..... for `$table2` in this case

Comment: You simply define what you want via `tablename.column` so you can either specify an existing column name, or use star * to indicate all columns from that table. in your case `v` is an alias to your `tablename` table as mentionned by comments

Answer (score 5):

In the SQL there is this string: `FROM $table2 v`
The table can be access now with the alias name `v`

You could use `*` for selecting all available columns from all joined tables
`v.*` uses only the columns from table `v`

**Example:**
Given are the following tables:
`TableA` with the columns `a1` and `a2`
`TableB` with the columns `a1` and `b2`

```
SELECT * FROM TableA JOIN TableB ON (...)
```

This would give an result set with all 4 columns

```
SELECT TableA.* FROM  TableA JOIN TableB ON (...)
```

This would give an result set only with the columns `a1` and `a2`

```
SELECT v.* FROM  TableA v JOIN TableB ON (...)
```

This is exactly the same as above, but with alias names

See also: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp

Answer (score 0):

See the `"From $table2 v"` portion of the SQL statement. That gives the table the alternative name v. This is called an alias.

If it was written fully it would be `"From $table2 AS v"`

The AS  keyword is optional and so is often omitted.